# I set socket MARK and TTL with iptables, but I can't read it from getsockopt?

Tags: linux, tcp, iptables

I run iptables-command on my linux server.

```
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m state --state NEW -j MARK --set-mark 100
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --save-mark
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j TTL --ttl-set 33
```

This is part of my server code, with that iptables policy, I expect to get the right TTL=33 and MARK=100 from my socket-fd.

```
void get_mark(int connfd) {
    int mark;
    socklen_t marklen = sizeof(mark);
    int n = getsockopt(connfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_MARK, &mark, &marklen);
    if (n) {
        printf("get mark failed!\n");
    } else {
        printf("fd:%d MARK:%d\n", connfd, mark);
    }
}

void get_ttl(int connfd) {
    int ttl;
    socklen_t ttllen = sizeof(ttl);
    int n = getsockopt(connfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, &ttllen);
    if (n) {
        printf("get ttl failed!\n");
    } else {
        printf("fd:%d TTL:%d\n", connfd, ttl);
    }
}
```

BUT I failed, the real result given MARK=0 and TTL=64.

```
fd:4 MARK:0
fd:4 TTL:64
```

What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

check the **net.ipv4.tcp_fwmark_accept** 
the net.ipv4.tcp_fwmark_accept should be set to 1